# Loop with two variables (one is pointer) in C programming

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop

I briefly have a problem about for loop with 2 variables.

 One variable classically `i=0 > to the end of bound` and 

the second one is `*(ptr->cost)` like that and show the value using the pointer.

I have a problem the second one actually I cant place it in for loop. I get the **cost**  variable from user and I want to print them **i and cost variables** together. But my codes just print i variables and one variable of cost.
This is my related code part:

```
void print_graph(struct node *ad[],int no_of_nodes){

    struct node *ptr = NULL;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<no_of_nodes; i++){
        ptr = ad[i];
        printf("\n Number %d node cost is = %d and its neighbours are :  ",i+1,*(ptr->cost));
        while(ptr != NULL){
            printf("%d\t ",ptr->data,*(ptr->cost));
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }  
}
```

and the out put
[image]

Node 1 should be 50, but output show it 70.

Also I think Cost variable does not included in for loop thats why it turns only one times and also reverse order. How can fix the problem?

This is my whole code

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
int* cost;};

typedef struct node nodes;

void read_graph(struct node *ad[], int no_of_nodes);
void print_graph(struct node *ad[],int no_of_nodes);

void main()
{
    int i,j,k,nodes;
    printf("\nEnter the number of nodes :");
    scanf("%d",&nodes);

    struct node *adj[nodes];
    for(i=0; i<nodes; i++)
        adj[i] = NULL;
    read_graph(adj,nodes);
    print_graph(adj,nodes);     

}

void read_graph(struct node *ad[], int no_of_nodes){
    struct node *new_node;
    int i,j,k,val;  
    int costs[10];
    for(i=0; i< no_of_nodes; i++){
        struct node *last = NULL;

        printf("\nFor Node : %d\n",i+1);        
        printf("\n%5d. nodes cost is: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&costs);

        printf("    Number of neighbours = ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&k);

        for(j=0; j<k; j++){
            printf("    Enter the %d. neighbours of %d : ",j+1,i+1);
            scanf("%d",&val);
            new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            new_node->data = val;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            (*new_node).cost = costs;  //////////////////////////////////////

            if(ad[i]== NULL)
                ad[i] = new_node;
            else
                last->next = new_node;
            last =  new_node;           

        }

    }
}

void print_graph(struct node *ad[],int no_of_nodes){

    struct node *ptr = NULL;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<no_of_nodes; i++){
        ptr = ad[i];
        printf("\n Number %d node cost is = %d and its neighbours are :  ",i+1,*(ptr->cost));
        while(ptr != NULL){
            printf("%d\t ",ptr->data,*(ptr->cost));
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, can anyone guide me about how should I follow path for sum cost and compare them for finding which one is lowest?

Comment: What is your while loop doing inside the for loop?

Comment: Why did you make 'cost' a pointer to int, rather than simply an int? It's used to store a numeric value, presumably.

Comment: @Steephen its written there which inside for loop. But I am not sure of the truth,

Comment: @jarmod because I need to keep address for adjacent cost.

Comment: Please don't show screen dumps of plain text; include the text in the question (treat it as 'code' — if you're fancy, include the line `<!-- language: lang-none -->` on its own, unindented and surrounded by blank lines, before the text.

Comment: `costs` is a local variable in `read_graph()`.  You store pointers to it in the adjacency graph.  When `read_graph()` returns, every single one of those pointers is invalid, and points at memory which will be reused for sundry other purposes.  This is not a recipe for happiness.  By far the easiest fix is to make your `cost` member a plain `int` variable and not a pointer.  If you must have pointers (why?) make sure that they point at memory that is allocated for as long as the adjacency list is, and remember to free it if it was allocated.

Comment: Also — `scanf("%d",&costs);` where you have `int costs[10];` is a major bug too.  You are passing an `int (*)[10]` but telling `scanf()` to expect an `int *`; happiness does not ensue (you keep overwriting the same element in `costs` each time you make the call).

Comment: OK, if you know it's always going to be 10 ints then just declare int cost[10] in the struct. If it's a variable number then you're going to have to dynamically allocate it using malloc(N * sizeof(int)) rather than simply pointing it at the automatic int costs[10] that you have now in read_graph().

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    int cost;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void read_graph(node *ad[], int no_of_nodes);
void print_graph(node *ad[],int no_of_nodes);

void main()
{
    int i,j,k,nodes;
    printf("\nEnter the number of nodes :");
    scanf("%d",&nodes);

    node *adj[nodes];
    memset(adj, 0, sizeof(node *) * nodes);
    read_graph(adj,nodes);
    print_graph(adj,nodes);     
}

void read_graph(node *ad[], int no_of_nodes){
    node *new_node;
    node *last;
    int i,j,k,val;  
    int cost;
    for(i=0; i< no_of_nodes; i++){
        last = NULL;

        printf("\nFor Node : %d\n",i+1);        
        printf("\n%5d. nodes cost is: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&cost);

        printf("    Number of neighbours = ");
        scanf("%d",&k);

        for(j=0; j<k; j++){
            printf("    Enter the %d. neighbours of %d : ",j+1,i+1);
            scanf("%d",&val);
            new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            new_node->data = val;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            new_node->cost = cost;

            if(ad[i]== NULL)
                ad[i] = new_node;
            else
                last->next = new_node;
            last =  new_node;           
        }
    }
}

void print_graph(node *ad[],int no_of_nodes){
    node *ptr = NULL;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<no_of_nodes; i++){
        ptr = ad[i];
        printf("\n Number %d node cost is = %d and its neighbours are :  ",i+1,ptr->cost);
        while(ptr != NULL){
            printf("%d\t ",ptr->data);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The code work well for your request, however I suggest redefining struct node like:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int id;
    int cost;
    int neighbours;
} node;
```